# Is there a way of include multiple conditions in a Python next function?

Tags: python, conditional-statements, iterator

The general idea is that I want to find the first value in each list that meets any of two conditions.
i.e.:
´

```
a = next((x for x in the_iterable if x > 3), default_value)
```

However, I want it to have multiple conditions, something like:

```
a = next((x for x in the_iterable if x > 3 or x-1 for x in the_iterable if x>2), default_value)
```

My code right now looks something like:

```
a = []
for x in iterable:
  if x>3:
    a.append(x)
    break
  elif x>4:
    a.append(x-1)
    break
```

Comment: Your code right now is much prettier than the ugly next stuff. I suggest you use that.

Comment: I think, a condition in your code id not  mathcing with in next statement, so `if  2<x<=3:x.append(x-1) break elif x>3: a.append(x) break`

Comment: Yes, the statement is not adding, it's not the real problem, just typed the general idea, the og one is much more complicated, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Your code right now is much prettier, but this would work:

```
a = next((
 (x - 1 if x > 4 else x) 
 for x in the_iterable 
 if (x > 3 or x > 4)
), default_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

No. `next` doesn't have conditions at all. It just takes an iterator and an optional default:

```
Help on built-in function next in module builtins:

next(...)
    next(iterator[, default])
    
    Return the next item from the iterator. If default is given and the iterator
    is exhausted, it is returned instead of raising StopIteration.
```

So not only can you not include multiple conditions, you cannot even include one.

If you mean to ask if you can include multiple conditions in a comprehension or generator expression, then that doesn't really have to do with the `next` function.

```
(x for x in expr if predicate(x) or second_predicate(x))
```

Python does have another builtin function, `iter`, that has a very simple built-in predicate, called the `sentinel`:

```
Help on built-in function iter in module builtins:

iter(...)
    iter(iterable) -> iterator
    iter(callable, sentinel) -> iterator
    
    Get an iterator from an object.  In the first form, the argument must
    supply its own iterator, or be a sequence.
    In the second form, the callable is called until it returns the sentinel.
```

The sentinel is a literal, so there's no way to make it multiple values.

Comment: Not only you are wrong, you are missinformating others, next CAN have a condition, maybe we do not understand 'condition' the same way, but take a look to the initial code in the question.

Comment: @Ferzimo You asked about the `next` function, but that is not where the condition applies. The condition is in the generator expression. It will apply whether or not you use `next` directly. That is why there are two pairs of parentheses, instead of just one for the function application. You can certainly apply multiple conditions inside the generator expression, combining them with Boolean operators like `and` and `or`.